# Heat equation using separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve a PDE using separation of variables.
The heat eq. is given by:
$$u_t = k(u_{rr}+ \frac{2}{r} u_r)$$
The boundary conditions are given by:
$$    \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = 0; \quad \text{for} \quad t>0. $$
and
$$    u(a,t) = u_{0}; \quad \text{for} \quad t>0. $$
where $u_0$ is a constant.
The initial condition is given by:
$$    u(r,0) = 0; \quad \text{for} \quad 0<r<a.$$.

**Attempt at solution:**
Let:  $u = R(r)T(t)$ be the solution to the PDE.
From this, we have:
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = R(r)T'(t)$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial r} = R'(r)T(t)$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial r^2} = R''(r)T(t)$$
BY substituting back into the PDE, we have:
$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}=k(\frac{R''(r)}{R(r)} + \frac{2}{r}\frac{R'(r)}{R(r)})= -\lambda^2; \quad \text{where} \quad \lambda > 0.$$
Here, $\lambda$ is the separation constant.
Then, we will get 2 ODEs given by:
$$T'(t)+ \lambda T(t)=0$$
$$k(rR''(r)+2R'(r)+\lambda rR(r))= 0$$
The solution to the first ODE is
$$ T = Ae^{- \lambda t}$$
How do I proceed from here and apply the BCs/ICs?

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
Lets $\ds{\varphi\pars{r,t} \equiv \on{u}\pars{r,t} - u_{0}}$ such that

$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\varphi_{t}} & \ds{=} & \ds{k\pars{\varphi_{rr} + {2 \over r}\,\varphi_{r}}}
\\[2mm]
&&\left.\begin{array}{rcl}
\ds{\varphi_{r}\pars{0,t}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\\[1mm]
\ds{\varphi\pars{a,t}} & \ds{=} & \ds{0}
\end{array}\right\}
\substack{\ds{Boundary} \\[0.5mm] \ds{Conditions}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{\varphi\pars{r,0}} & \ds{=} & \ds{-u_{0}}\
\pars{~Initial\ Condition~}
\end{array}\right.$

---

- Set $\ds{\varphi\pars{r,t} = \on{A}\pars{t}\on{B}\pars{r}}$. Then,
  \begin{align}
  \on{A}_{t}\on{B} & =
  k\pars{\on{A}\on{B}_{rr} + {2 \over r}\on{A}\on{B}_{r}}
  \\[2mm]
  {\on{A}_{t} \over \on{A}} & =
  k\pars{{\on{B}_{rr} \over \on{B}}+ {2 \over r}{\on{B}_{r} \over \on{B}}} = -q^{2}\,,\quad q \in \mathbb{R}
  \\[2mm]
  \on{A} &= -q^{2}\on{A}\,,\quad
  k\on{B}_{rr} + {2k \over r}\on{B}_{r} + q^{2}\on{B} = 0
  \end{align}
  Lets $\ds{\on{B} \propto {\expo{\alpha r} \over r}}$ which yields $\ds{\alpha = \pm \ic q/\root{k}}$. In order to satisfy the boundary condition at $\ds{r = 0}$, $\ds{\on{B} \propto {\sin\pars{qr/\root{k}}}/r}$. At $\ds{r = a}$, $\ds{\sin\pars{qa/\root{k}} = 0}$ $\ds{\implies q_{n} = n\,{\pi\root{k} \over a}\,,\quad n = 1,2,3,\ldots}$ The general solution becomes
  \begin{align}
  \varphi\pars{r,t} & =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\on{A}_{n}\pars{0}\exp\pars{-q_{n}^{2}\,t}
  {\sin\pars{q_{n}r/\root{k}} \over r}
  \\[5mm]
  -u_{0} & =
  \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}\on{A}_{n}\pars{0}
  {\sin\pars{q_{n}r/\root{k}} \over r}
  \\[5mm]
  &-u_{0}\
  \overbrace{\int_{0}^{a}r\sin\pars{{q_{n} \over \root{k}}\,r}
  \dd r}
  ^{\ds{-\,{\pars{-1}^{n}a^{2} \over n\pi}}}
  \\[2mm] & =
  \sum_{m = 1}^{\infty}\on{A}_{m}\pars{0}\
  \underbrace{\int_{0}^{a}\sin\pars{{q_{m} \over \root{k}}\,r}
  \sin\pars{{q_{m} \over \root{k}}\,r}\,\dd r}
  _{\ds{{a \over 2}\,\delta_{mn}}}
  \end{align}
  $\ds{\implies \on{A}_{n}\pars{0} =
  {2\pars{-1}^{n}au_{0} \over n\pi}}$.
- Finally
  $\ds{\pars{~\mbox{with}\
  q_{n} = n\,{\pi\root{k} \over a}~}}$,
  $$
  \bbx{\on{u}\pars{r,t} = u_{0} +
  {2au_{0} \over \pi}\,{1 \over r}\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
  {\pars{-1}^{n} \over n}\exp\pars{-q_{n}^{2}\,t}
  \sin\pars{{q_{n} \over \root{k}}\,r}}\\
  $$